# YUI 3: Getting the selected option's text

Tags: javascript, yui

I am working with YUI 3, coming from jQuery, but I have a question about YUI usage.

I have a select tag with some option tags:

```
 <select id="ownerSelector">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

I want to get the selected option's text.

Is there anything resembling jQuery's $('option:selected') extension in YUI 3?

I saw this over at http://www.jsrosettastone.com/#selectors that a way to do this is `Y.all('option[selected]')`, but that doesn't work.  (Either that, or I don't know which YUI module the [] selector syntax belongs to.)

If there is no shortcut, I noticed that when I query `Y.all('#ownerSelector option')`, I can see the NodeList array, and one of the options has a property called 'selected'. Is there a way to get at the selected option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
YUI().use("selector-css3", "node", function (Y) {
    var text = Y.one("#ownerSelector option:checked").get("text");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqPus/2/

Comment: Thank you for naming that module.  I loaded it, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like YUI 3 supports selector shortcuts.  This is what I could find on the YUI forums.

```
 var node = Y.one('#ownerSelector');
 node.get('options').item(node.get('selectedIndex')).get('text');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Y.one('#ownerSelector').get('value')
```

Comment: I think the question was how to get the text, not the value. Otherwise it would be correct :)